# Multithreaded Pipeline in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, pipeline

I have a problem regarding running multiple threads executing a pipeline in Java.

Say the 'input' of the pipeline is:

5 instructions namely: I1, I2, I3, I4, I5

If I1 has been fetched it will be now ready for decoding but `fetch` operation will not wait the `decode` task to finish. After transferring the fetched instructions to `decode`, the `fetch` operation will now get the next instruction I2, and so on.

It is a pipelining scheduling with five stages.

How do I simulate such a machine using java multithreading?

Comment: it's not a homework., it's part of my research topic., I must be able to generate pipeline scheduling in tabular form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you want to know *how* to implement such a thing: It is called a 'pipeline pattern'. If this is *not* homework, you could reuse an existing implementation of this pattern. One is available at:

http://code.google.com/p/pipelinepattern/

If this is homework, then your teacher might be expecting you to write it on your own from scratch. A good starting point is this two stage pipeline (where one thread reads lines from a file, and the other thread prints the lines):

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Synchronous_concurrency#Java

In the above example the two stages communicate via a `BlockingQueue` (i.e. stage 1 writes to the queue, and stage 2 reads it). If stage 1 is consistently faster than stage 2, the queue will get quite big). You can enforce operation of the stages in lockstep by using a `SynchronousQueue` instead [see comment #1 to this answer, for why].

If you need a five stage pipeline, you need to extend this by having 5 threads which have 4 queues between them:

```
in -> [s1] -> q12 -> [s2] -> q23 -> [s3] -> q34 -> [s4] -> q45 -> [s5] -> out
```

Above, each `[s*]` represents a stage (a thread) and each `qAB` represents a Queue being enqueued to by `[sA]` and dequeued from by `[sB]`

Comment: Good answer. Note that while a BlockingQueue would work, a SynchronousQueue would be a better representation of what actually happens in a CPU in my opinion.

Comment: Agreed. A CPU pipeline does work in lockstep. I have now mentioned this.

Comment: It is for my research topic in which I have to simulate a pipeline given a number of instruction and five stages of the pipeline. This is for educational purposes. I also need to optimize the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for giving me answers to my problem.

Comment: Hello sir., do you have other algorithm in generating the pipeline aside from using threads?

Comment: @Celine: Since the stages need to work in parallel, they are best implemented in separate threads. Also: I'm not sure what you mean by 'algorithm' in this case.